# Given a complex function that goes to infinity as z goes to infinity then it's a polynomial. (proof without Laurent series or singularity theory)

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I want to prove that given an analytical function $f(z)$ such that $\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} =\infty$ then $f(z)$ is a polynomial. However, i want to prove this without using Laurent series or theory of singularities.

My approach has been the following:

If the limit of a function is infinity that means that there is a compact disc centered in the origin such that the function doesnt take 0 values outside of it. Now, as the function has all it's zeroes inside of the disc, the number of zeros have to be finite as if they were infinite the function would have a sequence of zeros with an accumulation point an therefore be constantly zero. Now, I approached this by cleaning the function of zeros and getting to

$$f(z)=\Pi_i (z-z_i)^{l_i}g(z)$$

where $g(z)$ is an analytical function with no zeros.

Now id just have to prove that $g(z)$ is a constant and I'd be finished. However, I can't find a way to prove this.

I'd appreciate some help with this

Thanks in advabce

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Liouville's theorem. Suppose $g$ is bounded then it is constant, suppose not then look at the function $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ since $g$ does not vanish this is analytic and bounded because $g$ itself is not bounded(we were done if it was bounded) so we can take a compact disc outside which this function is bounded, so $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ must be constant. Either way we get that $g(z)$ is constant.

Here is a [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) to the wiki of the theorem, you can prove it without using the taylor expansion and they have outlined the proof on the website.

Comment: *"look at the function $\frac{1}{g(z)}$ since $g$ does not vanish this is analytic **and bounded** because $g$ itself is not bounded"*... How do you know this bold portion?  E.g. it is not true if $g(z)= \exp\big(z\big)$.  The fact that $\vert\frac{1}{g(z)}\vert$ can be bounded above by a polynomial for $\vert z\vert$ large enough is important information.